# How to load and parse .xlsx file using fetch API and XLSX library

Tags: parsing, fetch, xlsx

I'm importing these library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
```

and trying to fetch & parse local file saved in my project folder:

```
fetch('Eshop_product_list.xlsx').then(res => { 
    return res.blob();
}).then(res => {
    console.log('file:', res);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(res, {
        type: 'binary'
    });
});
```

But I can't get it working. I've tried different combinations of XLSX type arguments with `res.blob(), res.text(), res.bufferArray()` but everytime it is throwing an error.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `res.arrayBuffer()` instead of `res.bufferArray()`

Replaced in your example:

```
fetch('Eshop_product_list.xlsx').then(res => { 
    return res.arrayBuffer();
}).then(res => {
    console.log('file:', res);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(new Uint8Array(res), {
        type: 'array'
    });
});
```